# ABCPdf - Opening the PDF file

Tags: c#, abcpdf

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
theDoc.FontSize = 96;
theDoc.AddText("Hello World");
theDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("simple.pdf"));
theDoc.Clear();
```

I understand that this creates the pdf and saves it. When I click on the link I have created for this I want the pdf to just pop up in a pdf viewer, instead of me having to go to the actual location to see what it looks like after I have saved it. How do I get it to open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide a link to this file in your view which would allow the user to download the file once it is saved:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/simple.pdf")">simple.pdf</a>
```

And if you want it to open in a new window:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/simple.pdf")" target="_blank">simple.pdf</a>
```